# ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:latest" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 3

Tags: node.js, angular, google-cloud-platform, angular8, google-cloud-build

I am trying built angular 8 dist using cloudbuild and deploying it on a vm

GitHub link of my angular 8 app https://github.com/nishitkumar123/angular-on-gcp

cloudbuild.yaml

steps:

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:latest"

  args: ["install"]
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:latest"

  args: [run, ng, "--", build, "--prod"]
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"

  args:

  [

  "compute",

  "scp",

  "--recurse",

  "dist",

  "la-test-angular-node-1:/var/",

  "--zone=us-central1-a",

  ]

I am getting this error

ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:latest" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 3

Note:- has any one deployed angular8 app using cloudbuild.yaml file please share your opinion on this

[more details of error on cloudbuild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2KvJ.jpg)

Comment: are the installed packages locally or globally?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere , i created my angular project using "ng new angular-on-gcp" after that i checked it using "ng-serve --open" and uploaded the code in the repo.

Comment: Please do not create duplicates of your own questions. Only publish one and focus in one. If more details are needed, add them in just one. Creating more questions will not make the community answer faster https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72500225/error-while-deploying-angular-built-from-cloud-build-to-vm